# Load images from unsecured domain (http://...) not loading with AlamofireImage

Tags: ios, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am using `AlamofireImage` to load images from URLs and whenever the URL is something like `https://picsum.photos/200/300` it works. Whenever it comes from our current developing server `http://15.XXX.XX.XX:8180` they don't load and it says timeout.

I have enabled the App Transport Security:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
          <true/>
    </dict>
```

Any idea how to fix it? It won't be like this in the future but I need to show a beta to a client and at the moment we don't have the SSL certificate.

Thank you

Comment: How did you debug it? Can you open the image in the browser with the *exact link*? 
e.g. `http://15.XXX.XX.XX:8180/image.jpeg`

Comment: @RufatMirza yeah, the link is correct and there's an image there. I get a timeout through the app. My way of debugging it is that if I put any other url, it works perfectly just not on the http://15.XXX.XX.XX:8180/